# Jackson JSONSerializer: Write value in another context (from root)

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, fasterxml

I have a Java Object like this:

```
@Data
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MetadataValue<V> {

    private @Nullable V value;

    private @Nullable Integer maximum;

}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyClass {

    @JsonSerialize(using = MetadataValueSerializer.class)
    MetadataValue<Integer> integerValue;

    MySubClass mySubClass;

}
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MySubClass {

    @JsonSerialize(using = MetadataValueSerializer.class)
    MetadataValue<Integer> integerValue;

}
```

And I want to serialize it in this way, that it results something like this:

```
{
    "integerValue": 1,
    "mySubClass": {
        "integerValue": 2
    },
    "_metadata" : {
        "integerValue": {
            "maximum": 10
        },
        "mySubClass": {
            "integerValue": {
                "maximum": 10
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

At the moment I have no idea ho to resolve it, because I try to use the method: `getOutputContext()` of `JsonGenerator`. But there are only read methods to navigate through the `JSONObject`.

Any idea how I can resolve this use case?

Thanks

Comment: Which class do you want to serialize?

Comment: Oh sorry I want to serialize: MyClass.

Comment: Why don't you consider reorganizing your structure?

Comment: The use case is usually more complex and this structure is already fix. But the implementation of the metadata seems ugly. So I hope there is a solution to solve it with the serializer.